# Selecting DataFrame rows: why is the result filled with NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I would like to select data where only the submission date is greater than '2018/11/14 01:26PM'.

The code below is what I have so far, but all other columns in the dataset gets populated with a value of nan. What am I doing wrong?

```
d = datetime.strptime('2018-11-14 01:26PM', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%p')
data[data['submission_date'] > d]
```

Data sample below:

```
 ID    Name   submission_date  
 12    Mike   2018-11-14 01:26PM
 13    Mark   2018-11-14 02:00PM
 14    Taylor 2018-11-14 03:26PM
 14    Taylor 2018-11-15 03:26PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know almost nothing about `pandas` but, using your question as a learning exercise, I found the following pattern.  When `data.columns` is initialized with a flat list, which creates an `Index` object, all is well:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame( numpy.random.randn( 5, 2 ) )
data.columns=[ 'one', 'two' ]
print( data )

# Output:
#         one       two
# 0 -1.242567  0.430084
# 1 -1.125710 -0.342616
# 2 -0.514284  0.479382
# 3  0.108649 -0.789272
# 4  1.489155  0.842427

criterion = data[ 'one' ] > 0    # NB: criterion.shape is (5,): it is one-dimensional
print( data[ criterion ] )

# Output:
#         one       two
# 3  0.108649 -0.789272
# 4  1.489155  0.842427
```

However, if I change the dimensionality of the column structure (creating a `MultiIndex`) then I can recreate the NaN syndrome you describe:

```
data.columns = [ [ 'one', 'two' ] ]   # note the double-nesting
print(data)  # it "looks" identical to how it did before...

# Output:
#         one       two
# 0 -1.242567  0.430084
# 1 -1.125710 -0.342616
# 2 -0.514284  0.479382
# 3  0.108649 -0.789272
# 4  1.489155  0.842427

criterion = data[ 'one' ] > 0   # but this criterion.shape is now (5,1): it's two-dimensional...
print( data[ criterion ] )

# Output:
#         one two
# 0       NaN NaN
# 1       NaN NaN
# 2       NaN NaN
# 3  0.108649 NaN
# 4  1.489155 NaN
```

It depends on the (superficially invisible) details of your `DataFrame`'s column structure.  It's very surprising to me that there was no warning or exception when you performed the slicing, and I can't imagine any context in which the NaN-ridden result would be the sensible, expected outcome.

Anyway, the problem can clearly be circumvented by reshaping the array you're using to index your data, so that its shape is `(5,)` again:

```
print( data[ criterion.values.flatten() ] )    # back to sanity

# Output:
#         one       two
# 3  0.108649 -0.789272
# 4  1.489155  0.842427
```

However if you don't want to take advantage of any particular `MultiIndex` behavior provided by your existing column structure, then the more elegant solution (indicated by your comment) may be simply to reassign `data.columns` to ensure that it's a flat list to start with.

Comment: I renamed the columns with single square brackets, and it works as you mentioned above. Very helpful.

Comment: NB: digging a little deeper, it seems that nested lists of columns create (and whatever routine created your `DataFrame` might otherwise have set up) a `MultiIndex` object instead of an `Index`, in `data.columns`.   I don't know enough yet to know what a `MultiIndex` is capable of, but you might want to make sure that you're not throwing away some essential functionality that it provides.